# How to setup these relations correct in Backpack for Laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a Problem with relations in Laravel / with Backpack for Laravel.

This program is for creating menues for my dad´s restaurant.

I have these tables:

```
- dishes (Table with the Names of the Dishes)
-- id (auto inc)
-- menuname (Name of the Dish)

- weeklymenues 
-- id (auto inc)
-- start_date (Monday of the selected week)
-- end_date (Friday of the selected week)
-- menu_monday (There should be the id of the dish)
-- menu_tuesday (...)
-- menu_wednesday (...)
.....
```

How can i do that correctly?

In the CRUD Controller i am setting the Field:

```
        $this->crud->addField([
        'label' => "Monday",
        'type' => 'select2',
        'name' => 'menu_mondy', // the db column for the foreign key
        'entity' => 'menu', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'menuname', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => "App\Models\Menu" // foreign key model
    ]);
```

And in the menues model i have set this relation:

```
public function menu() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Menu');
    }
```

Everytime I want to save the CRUD, the program wants to save something in the dishes table:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dish_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `weeklymenues` set `dish_id` = 1, `weeklymenues`.`updated_at` = 2019-06-25 14:13:14 where `id` = 15)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I set the relations correct?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Are "dishes" (from the table definition) and "Menu" (from the code) actually the same thing?

In your field definition, you set the model to be the "menu" class, shouldn't it be the "dishes" class?

I would have used the relationship type

```
CRUD::addField([
   'label' => 'Monday',
    'type' => 'relationship',
    'name' => 'menu', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
    'attribute' => 'menuname', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    'model' => \App\Models\dishes::class, // foreign key model
    'placeholder' => 'Select a dish for Monday'
]);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
---
-c:\xampp\htdocs\bpwebsite\app\Models\weeklymenues.php
---
protected $fillable = ['start_date', 'end_date', 'menu_monday']
---
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low-quality posts. Please add some explanation for your code

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with the question